# What is the purpose of single operator equal sign in ruby?

Tags: ruby

I've seen this a couple times :

```
if foo = bar
  # do something
end
```

Is this syntactically appropriate? Does it differ from? :

```
if foo == bar
   # do something
end
```

Comment: It's the assignment operator. It's possibly also a typo (using = instead of == is a common source of hard to find bugs in languages that allow this).

Comment: @Wooble: or a source of concise elegant code :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Concise, yes (some would say terse). But elegant? *Very* debatable.

Comment: @delnan: matter of taste, obviously. I think it's elegant. :)

Comment: It's only elegant in languages that force you to declare variables and allow you to combine the condition with the declaration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if foo = bar
end
```

it can be read as this:

```
foo = bar
if foo
  # do stuff
end
```

Assignment operator in ruby returns a value that was assigned. This makes it very useful in some situations, thanks to the fact that ruby has very simple rules about what's true and what's not.

Here's a typical example where assignment is used in a condition (not a good one, though, because with files you should use [`each_line`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-each_line) and a block, but you get the idea):

```
f = File.open(...)
while line = f.gets
  # do something with a line from file
end
```

This, on the other hand, is a comparison operator, not assignment operator. It returns a boolean value if `foo` and `bar` were equal.

```
if foo == bar
```

[edit] An example that demonstrates that using this pattern may have a real impact on the verbosity of code. Look at this nested conditional expression:

```
a = f(1)
result = if a
  b = g(a)
  if b
    c = h(b)
    if c
      2 * c
    end
  end
end
```

Using this pattern we can write instead (note how I [surround the assignments](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide)):

```
result = if (a = f(1)) && (b = g(a)) && (c = h(b))
  2 * c 
end
```

Comment: I'd add 2 things: 1) It's real useful in conditionals with more than one branch so variables are only assigned when needed. Otherwise it leads to more verbose branch structures. 2) some (https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide) give as idiomatic `if (var = value)` to emphasize it's an assignment.

Comment: @tokland: feel free to edit the post :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: as you wish :-)

Answer (score 3):

They are completely different.  The first will assign the value of `bar` to `foo` and then evaluate if that value is truthy (not `nil` or `false`).  The second does a straightforward comparison.

Answer (score 2):

the first one assigns the value of bar to foo.
after that the new value in foo is evaluated toward true or false.

the second one check, if foo and bar are the same.

you lose the value of foo in the first one

Answer (score 0):

It's valid code, but probably an unintentional bug.

Some people may try to get fancy with their code and do both an assignment and an if check in the same line (like your first example), but it's so similar to a common typo that it's well-known as one of those 'bad code smells' that should be avoided for clarity.

Comment: This is actually quite common

Comment: @SergioTulentsev - seriously? Maybe it's my background in other languages where this sort of thing is an anti-pattern, and one of those cases where the slightly longer form is recommended for clarity (so someone reviewing the code knows it's intentional and not a typo).

Comment: IMO, this technique should not be used. Because the reader has to spend time and figure out whether the usage is a typo or intentional. Would have been a no-brainer if the assignment had been done on a separate line.

Comment: Great discussion. I actually like the truncated version ( now that I know what it means ), but its going to take some getting used to.

Comment: @Zabba: On a single branched conditional, yes, this idiom just saves one line and it may seem whimsical. But on multi-line branches you may obtain a real gain, the code is less verbose and you save nesting conditionals (which are hard to read). So in the end is a trade-off.

Comment: Yes, good for programmers who know what this construct is. Aside, there is a reason why almost every C compiler spits out a warning for such assignment. Cheers.

Comment: @Zabba. Indeed, Python also forbade it for this reason. Personally I am a bit puzzled with the argument, I do lots and lots of typing errors, howevery I use this pattern *all the time* and I've never (not once that I remember) confused a `==` by `=`.